# In this code the Runnable is not instantiated. Why?

Tags: java

```
// Runnable cannot instantiate
public class Thread4 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable());
    }
}
```

> `//Runnable cannot instantiate`

Why? Although in the other program it's instantiating with the same code.

Comment: Runnable is an interface

Comment: That's not how you create a thread. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: You cannot instantiate an interface. Nor an abstract class.

Comment: runnable is interface and why u r passing to Thread Constructer it is not possible

Comment: Can you show in what program it worked?

Comment: Hi Mjsoft, I am running a single thread so implementing the runnable interface into the Thread constructor itself. Is it something wrong I am doing? It worked on the other small programs

Answer (score 3):

`Runnable` is an interface, not a class. In order to instantiate it, you must supply a class that implements the interface (or a lambda expression or method reference if you are using Java 8 or later).

For example:

```
Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {public void run() {}});
```

Here I defined an anonymous class that implements `Runnable` and created an instance of that class.

Comment: Thanks Eran, however in Eclipse I am not getting the auto suggestion as well to implement the method for run. The class is already there.

Comment: @NishantSaxena I don't understand what you are asking in this comment. Eclipse does offer auto complete - if you write `Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable` and then hit CTRL+SPACE, you'll get an option to choose an anonymous class instance.

Comment: @Eran, that's right but did not get any auto completion from Eclipse as well for this method.

Answer (score 2):

Directly you can't pass **new Runnable()** inside new **Thread()**. You need to create an implemented class (for example : MyTestRunnable.java) which implement Runnable Interface and pass **new MyTestRunnable()** in new Thread().

```
public class MyTestRunnable implements Runnable {
    public void run(){
       System.out.println(" .... ");
    }
  }


public class Thread4 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       Thread t1 = new Thread(new MyTestRunnable());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Uma Shankar, however I am running a single thread hence implementing the runnable interface into the Thread Constructor rather than implementing through the class. The other program worked fine with the same method

Comment: public class Thread2Runnableinterface1 {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  Thread one = new Thread(new Runnable() {

   
   public void run() {
    for(int i=0; i<10;i++) {
     
    
      System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getId()+":"+ i);
    }
   }
   
  }); one.start();

 }

}

Comment: @NishantSaxena hm, you should really wrap your code with the ` character on StackOverflow before posting it in comments. Check the "help" link on the right when editing a comment.